# How to disable/turnoff autocomplete in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Most modern browsers can be configured to remember the information the user fills in for form and password fields on web sites. This feature is called Form and Password Auto-completion. 
My question is how to turn off autocompletion in Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Autocomplete is a setting of the _browser_, not the content management system that delivers the HTML, like SharePoint. The user decides whether or not they want autocomplete turned on in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute autocomplete="off" to all input elements in the form with javascript.